# How to auto-focus after changing display from none to block?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of `input`s under a list of `div`s respectively. I have a button that when clicked it will switch one input from from not display to display. This is something like:

```
if (switched) {
        document.getElementById("div-xxx").style.display = "block";
}
```

However, is there a way I could make the `input` inside the displayed `div` being auto focused after this switch? I tried something like

```
document.getElementById('input-xxx').autofocus = true;
```

after the `display` code, but there is no autofocus at all.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById('input-xxx').focus()` will change the focus to the selected element.

`document.getElementById('input-xxx').setAttribute('autofocus', true)` will assign the `autofocus` attribute to the html element

Comment: This doesn't work on my end. Maybe by changing the display the `focus` stuff was not refreshed?

Comment: you may have to set the previous item that had `autofocus` to `false` like document.getElementById('old-input').setAttribute('autofocus', false)

Answer (score 1):

object.focus(); will help

```
if (switched) {
        document.getElementById('div-xxx').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('input-xxx').focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was

```
    if (switched) {

        document.getElementById('div-xxx').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('old-input').setAttribute('autofocus', false);
        document.getElementById('input-xxx').setAttribute('autofocus', true);
        document.getElementById('input-xxx').focus();
}
```